# HIghChart Point are not stacking as per design

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have tried to create the line graph without line in highchart. i am looking for desired result as shown in the image below. I have two main issues.

1. Dot are showing on top of each other as per design it should parallel. i can the adjustment and make them in one line but that cant hold more then 5-6 dots. since data will be dynamic and it can have same values for other series of data.
2. secondly blue the line on the season is out of the box and touching mid of the another season. how to fix this.

i have my code here
https://jsfiddle.net/mossawir/chn8u3L5/65/

```
                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                  chart: {

                },
                title: {
                  text: ''
                },
                plotOptions: {
                            line: {
                                marker: {
                                symbol: 'circle',
                              // fillColor: 'blue',
                                radius: 5,
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                  xAxis: {
                  gridLineWidth: 1,
                    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    plotLines: [{
                    label: { 
                        text: 'Winter', // Content of the label. 
                      align: 'left', // Positioning of the label. Default to center.
                      x: +10, // Amount of pixels the labelrepositioned according to the alignment. 
                      y: +20 ,    
                      rotation: 0,
                  },
                  value: -0.5,
                  dashStyle: 'dash',
                  color: 'red',
                  zIndex: 9,
                },{
                label: { 
                      text: 'Spring', // Content of the label. 
                      align: 'left', // Positioning of the label. Default to center.
                      x: +10, // Amount of pixels the labelrepositioned according to the alignment. 
                      y: +20 ,    
                      rotation: 0,
                  },
                  value: 2.5,
                  dashStyle: 'dash',
                  color: 'red',
                  zIndex: 9,
                },{
                    label: { 
                      text: 'Summer', // Content of the label. 
                      align: 'left', // Positioning of the label. Default to center.
                      x: +10, // Amount of pixels the labelrepositioned according to the alignment. 
                      y: +20 ,    
                      rotation: 0,
                  },
                  value: 5.5,
                  dashStyle: 'dash',
                  color: 'red',
                  zIndex: 9,
                },{
                    label: { 
                      text: 'Autom', // Content of the label. 
                      align: 'left', // Positioning of the label. Default to center.
                      x: +10, // Amount of pixels the labelrepositioned according to the alignment. 
                      y: +20 ,    
                      rotation: 0,
                  },
                  value: 8.5,
                  dashStyle: 'dash',
                  color: 'red',
                  zIndex: 9,
                }],
                min: 0
              },

              yAxis: {

              },

              series: [{
                data: [29.9, null, 130.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4], 
                lineWidth: 0,
                color: 'green',
              },
              {
                data: [29.9, 12, 137.4, 29.2, 144.0,null, 135.6, 135.6, null, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4], 
                lineWidth: 0,
                color: 'red',
              }, 
              {
                showInLegend: false,
                data: [{
                  x: -1,
                  y: 180,
                }, 180, 180, 180, 180],
                color: 'blue',
                dashStyle: 'solid',
                lineWidth: 1,
                pointPlacement: "on",
                marker: {
                  enabled: false,
                  
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                states: {
                  inactive: {
                    enabled: false
                  }
                }
              }]

            });
```

Screenshot of design:
[image: screenshot of design]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you’re facing two issues with your Highcharts implementation.

**Dots on top of each other**: Highcharts plots the points in the order they are provided in the data array. If you have multiple points with the same x-value (i.e., they fall in the same category on the x-axis), they will be plotted on top of each other. To avoid this, you can introduce a small offset to the x-values of the points in the same category. However, this might not be ideal if you have more than 5-6 dots.

**Line out of the box**: The issue with the line going out of the box and touching the middle of another season is due to the value you’ve set for the plotLines. The value corresponds to the x-value where the line is drawn. If you want the line to be drawn at the boundary between two categories, you should set the value to be the index of the second category minus 0.5. For example, if you want to draw a line between ‘Jan’ and ‘Feb’, the value should be 1 - 0.5 = 0.5.

Here’s how you can modify your plotLines:

```
plotLines: [{
    label: { 
        text: 'Winter',
        align: 'left',
        x: +10,
        y: +20 ,    
        rotation: 0,
    },
    value: 2.5, // changed from -0.5
    dashStyle: 'dash',
    color: 'red',
    zIndex: 9,
},{
    label: { 
        text: 'Spring',
        align: 'left',
        x: +10,
        y: +20 ,    
        rotation: 0,
    },
    value: 5.5, // changed from 2.5
    dashStyle: 'dash',
    color: 'red',
    zIndex: 9,
},{
    label: { 
        text: 'Summer',
        align: 'left',
        x: +10,
        y: +20 ,    
        rotation: 0,
    },
    value: 8.5, // changed from 5.5
    dashStyle: 'dash',
    color: 'red',
    zIndex: 9,
},{
    label: { 
        text: 'Autom',
        align: 'left',
        x: +10,
        y: +20 ,    
        rotation: 0,
    },
    value: 11.5, // changed from 8.5
    dashStyle: 'dash',
    color: 'red',
    zIndex: 9,
}]
```